# Unwanted code suggestion in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, autocomplete, anaconda

In recent times, when ever I use jupyter notebook, I'm getting unwanted code suggestions from previous code snippets and comments. These suggestions get auto filled if I clicked right arrow key.

I tried uninstalling anaconda and re install it again. Please anyone help me to fix it.[image]